# How can I declare and initialize a VB.Net structure in a Form class to define a variable that contains all DataGridView columns in separate variables?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, initialization, declaration

When I want to use a specific column index, I can use the column object define by Visual Studio designer

```
sAccount = grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells.Item(Col_Account.Index).Value
```

where `Col_Account` object is defined automatically by Visual Studio in `Form.Designer.vb` file in following line

```
Friend WithEvents Col_Account As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

The problem is that it is not very easy to find column's name defined manually using Visual Studio WinForm editor in a Form.

So I decide to create a structure in which I will put all columns defined in Designer Visual Studio as this

```
   Public Structure GridColumns
        Public Account       = Col_Account
        Public Communication = Col_Communication
        Public Amount        = Col_Amount
   End Structure
```

and that I can use in Intellisense to find very quickly all column's name in typing

```
GridColumns.
```

When I compile this code, I receive following error code

```
BC30469: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
```

That is not working.

The only solution, that I have found is to define following structure

```
Public Structure GridColumns
    Public Account       As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Public Communication As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Public Amount        As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
End Structure

Public xColumns As GridColumns
```

and to initialize his members in `Me.Load` Form handle as this

```
Private Sub FrmSearch_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles Me.Load

    With xColumns
        .Account       = Col_Account
        .Amount        = Col_Amount
        .Communication = Col_Communication
    End With
```

After compiling, I can now type `xColumns.` to see all possible column's names usable in my code.

[image]

Is there a simple solution to implement what I want ? A solution that mix declaration and initialisation in only one place ?

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, however from the title to your question you want to… _”… define a variable that contains all DataGridView columns?_” … ? … I am not sure “why” you want this variable as it would appear to me that the “Grid” itself would clearly fall into that category… it is a `DataGridView` variable AND IT “contains” all of the grid columns. Why would you want another variable to “duplicate” this data?

Comment: I want these variables to facilitate columns selection with Intellisense ! Another solution would be to prefix all column's variables with Col_ and to use intellisense on Form object. But this solution doesn't work when Form contains more than one DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work using Visual Studio 2022 and I use following solution

```
Public Structure GridColumns
    Public Shared Account       As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = Frm.Col_Account
    Public Shared Communication As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = Frm.Col_Communication
    Public Shared Amount        As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = Frm.Col_Amount
End Structure
```

Example of use in VB.Net code

```
   Private Sub grid_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grid.CellClick
        If e.RowIndex < 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Select Case e.ColumnIndex
            Case GridColumns.Edit.Index 'click on Image "PENCIL"
                Dim sNoSeq = grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells.Item(GridColumns.YearNoSeq.Index).Value
                Dim sPersonalAccount = grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells.Item(GridColumns.Account.Index).Value
                nPayementGridIndex = e.RowIndex
                Call frmMDI.LoadDetailForm(sNoSeq, sPersonalAccount)
```

With this solution, I can define multiple `tabs` in same `Form` that contains each one grid.

When I reference a specific column, I use

```
TabAccountColumns.Account.Index
```

or

```
TabCountryColumns.Name.Index
```

The list of alls columns of a grid are now in a specific variable that I can use instead of `Frm` variable in which all columns of all grids are mixed.

It is certainly more proper.